# can we call a native method from javascript with another function name as a parameter to the method?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a hybrid app:

Native code:

Main activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //To display the alert
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize,
                long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(estimatedSize * 1);
        }
    });


    openCamera=new OpenCamera(webView,AvivaInsureActivity.this);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(openCamera,"camera");

    //load  html5 page
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/home.html");

}
```

Class :

```
public class OpenCamera  {
...
public void setName(String name){
name=name;
....
}
```

javascript+html:

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function openMsg(msg){ 
  camera.setName("sneha");
  }
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div class='content'></div>
 <div class='buttons'><input type='button' class='yesB' value='Yes' />
 <input class='yesB' type='button' value='No' /></div>
 </div>
 <input type="button" onclick="openMsg('Do you wish')"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Is there a way I can pass a function name say `addInt()` as a parameter to

```
 camera.setName("sneha");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as arguments, or function names as attributes of other objects.

The first example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('Hello World');
}

function bar(arg) {
    arg();
}

bar(foo);  //Console output: 'Hello World'
```

In the second example, you could put a number of methods into a Javascript object, and then pass the object with a string of the method's name to call the method:

```
function Obj() {
    this.methodOne = function() {
        console.log('This is method one');
    }

    this.methodTwo = function() {
        console.log('This is method two');
    }
}

function methodCaller(objArg, methodName) {
    objArg[methodName]();
}

var anObj = new obj();

methodCaller(anObj, 'methodOne'); //Outputs "This is method one"
methodCaller(anObj, 'methodTwo'); //Outputs "This is method two"
```